# How to filter out updated records from CTE in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I am trying to perform an update and insert operation on a partitioned table using the same CTE. The update query works perfectly fine. But during insert, I just want those records from CTE which were not updated so that I can make an optimal insert with least cost.

Below is my table and query :

```
create table scientist (id integer, firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100));
insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (1, 'albert', 'einstein');
insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (2, 'isaac', 'newton');
insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (3, 'marie', 'curie');
select * from scientist;

alter table scientist add constraint id_pk  PRIMARY KEY  ("id");
with temp(id, firstname, lastname) as (
  Select * 
  from (values(1, 'albert','besra'),
              (5, 'abc', 'def')
       ) as a(id, firstname, lastname)
),
updated as( 
  update scientist s 
    set lastname = t.lastname 
  from temp t 
  where s.id = t.id returning t.*
)
Select * 
from updated;
```

At present, it is returning all the rows. I was able to filter out records which were updated but that increased the total cost of my operation.

```
where not exists (Select 1 from updated where updated.id = temp.id )
```

Is there a way I can do that ?

Comment: Wouldn't [ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) work for this?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver On Conflict didnt work for tables which are partitioned. It behaves abnormally in those cases.

Comment: Then you need to update your question to indicate that you are working on partitioned tables.